# What happens with activations?

Tags: image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

I am playing with convolution network, assembling something between AlexNet and ResNet. Not very deep, about 10 conv. layers including 2 through residual connection, and 3 fully-connected layes at the end. Relu activations, but also tried ELU and sigmoid a bit. Achieved good results with 25 classes (up to 80% top-1 accuracy) and now trying on ImageNet with 1000 classes. And what I get is often stucking near random-quality choice (i.e. accuracy of 0.1% on 1000 classes and corresponding loss) or improving up to like 0.5% accuracy and then dropping back.

This happens with recommended for Adam learning rate of 0.001, a bit less, 2e-4, as well with much smaller l. rates, like 1e-5. What is strange, with small l. rates everything is even more ugly, in contrast to expected slow but reliable learning.

What I have found is that activations starting from middle levels start to decrease a lot. So different channels look like

[image]
(base image is [image]).

If we plot channels’ min-max changes through epochs, we’ll see 
[image] This is for two different images, with dotted line and on the right axis – standard deviation of activations.
The corresponding train loss improvement and worsening is dimly visible here, blue line:
[image]

**What is this? Vanishing gradients? Is the network too deep?** Shouldn't batch normalization struggle with that? What is the solution, to adjust learning rate continuously?

And everything happens quite fast. I use mini-epochs, 20000 images each, so 1 on my plots is actually 1/60 of normal epoch.

I was able to train 4 times less wide variant of the network on 110 classes, got 42% accuracy, looks reasonable. There I don’t see such big drops. Didn’t notice improvement with SGD, different batch sizes, but noticed that without augmentation learning is faster and less prone to this problem.

**Update**: I was able to reproduce this on smaller net :) . It learns well with learning rate 5e-4 and batch 64, then 2e-4 and then doesn’t learn much with l.r. 1-e4 and batch like 384 or bigger or quickly degrades with l.r. like 5e-5 or less.
I didn’t mention one of tricks I use: squeeze-and-excitation. So it can apparently lead to massive activations changes. And really there are excitation layers with activations in order of 10-50, even while everything looks fine. 
Now trying to struggle with this without success for some reason. I added

```
def near1Regularizer(activationVector):                  # <----
    return 0.01 * K.mean((1 - activationVector) ** 2)

…
se_feature = Dense(channel // ratio,
                       activation='relu',
                   name='dense_exc_%d' % (g_excLayerCount * 2 - 1),
                       # kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                   kernel_initializer=My1PlusInitializer(1.0 / 256),
                       use_bias=True,
                       bias_initializer='zeros')(se_feature)
assert se_feature._keras_shape[1:] == (1,1,channel//ratio)
se_feature = Dense(channel,
                   activation='sigmoid',
                   name='dense_exc_%d' % (g_excLayerCount * 2),
                   kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                   use_bias=True,
                   bias_initializer='zeros',
                   activity_regularizer=near1Regularizer)(se_feature)    # <----
se_feature = keras.layers.multiply([input_feature, se_feature])
```

and getting

[image]

The regularization applied near 90 by x. The error also started to increase after a dozen of mini-epochs...

**Update 2**: reproduced on simpler and smaller net (3 convolution blocks with squeeze-and-excitation and 3 dense blocks) and on small AlexNet (1/16 wide and 110 classes). Very surprizingly, convolution layers activations in order of 100s are very typical, they exist even in pretrained full AlexNet.

Comment: Was able to reproduce this on smaller net and added more info